# How to create tables in Oracle DB from the set of *.sql files

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the set of *.sql files (>200) which contains scripts of tables creation. How can I apply all of them automatically to Oracle DB?

I use Oracle SQL Developer environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a "driver" sql file, and call that from sqlplus - example, if you have
script1.sql, script2.sql, create a file, "driver.sql" and include:

```
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In which enviroment are you working? Give a bit more information please.

If u use SQLPLUS try this

```
SQL > @{path}{file}
```

For Example

```
SQL > @/usr/bin/script.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing them with SQL*Plus.

From command line:

> > sqlplus @script1.sql @script2.sql

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Developer, just open the script file and run it as a script (F5).

Or in a SQL Worksheet use an at reference to the script file:

```
@[drive:]\path\to\script1.sql
@[drive:]\path\to\script2.sql
...
@[drive:]\path\to\scriptn.sql
```

then just run that line (F9) or the entire SQL Worksheet as a script (F5).

Comment: I have large numbers of sql files ( >200 ). So I believe there is more suitable way to apply them.